# Stopwatch run in background sleep mode

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have built a basic app with a stopwatch on it. It runs off 3 buttons - play, pause, and reset on a navigation bar which write to a label called timerLabel.

The trouble is as soon as the app is closed or the iPhone goes into sleep mode the stopwatch stops. I've looked for the answer in other questions and it seems that the only way around it is to record the actual time when the app goes off and record the time when it reawakens and compare the difference - then write this to the label

Trouble is I have absolutely no idea how to incorporate that into my current code. I don't even know how to get the time. Here is my code from my view controller.

```
func updateTimer() {

    time++

    updateTimeDisplay()

}

func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    let h = seconds / 3600
    let m = (seconds % 3600) / 60
    let s = (seconds % 60)
    return (h, m, s)
}

func pauseTimer() {
    timer.invalidate()
}

func startTimer() {
    if !timer.valid {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)        }
    else {
    print("The Stopwatch has already started!")
    }
}

func resetTimer() {
    time = 0
    timer.invalidate()
    updateTimeDisplay()

}

func updateTimeDisplay() {

    let (h, m, s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(time)
    let timeToDisplay = String(format:"%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s)
    timerLabel.text  = timeToDisplay

}
```

Comment: NSTimer is a no-go for background running.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an `NSTimer` in the background, and your app will not run for long there anyway.

When the application enters background, you should stop the timer and take a note of the current time. Then when the application resumes again you should restart the timer, and calculate how long the app was in the background to update the display accordingly.

Comment: So if I create a variable to record the current time and run this code when the user presses the start button. The on applicationwillenterbackground them invalidate the timer. Then on applicationwillenterforeground minus the current time from the stored timed in the variable and then write that to the label and restart nstimer. Does that sound about right?